# Enabling a button using select box

Tags: javascript, angular-material

Simply I have two radio buttons when the first radio button is selected one select box appears and when the radio button is selected two select box appears. After this, I have one button "SUBMIT" now I want that when I select first radio then the submit button must be enabled but when I select second radio button then the button must be disabled till both of the select box doesn't have some value.
I am using the form in HTML taking form-group to consider all the fields, when all the fields have some value then the only button will get enabled but in case of the above situation I got stuck.

```
**This is my javascript code.
I m new in this plz help.**


function statecheck(){
    if (document.getElementById('state').checked = true) {
      document.getElementById('ifstate').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('ifapmc').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('ifapmc').disabled = true;
    }
  }

  function stateapmccheck(){
    if (document.getElementById('apmc').checked = true) {
      document.getElementById('ifapmc').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('ifstate').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('ifstate').disabled = true;
    }
  }
```

**This is my Angular material code**

```
    <div>
        <label>Registration Level: </label>&nbsp;
        <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" 
    formControlName="choosereglevel" #reglevel>
              <mat-radio-button value="1" id="state" 
    onclick="javascript:statecheck();" color="primary">State</mat-radio 
 button>&nbsp;
              <mat-radio-button value="2" id="apmc" 
    onclick="javascript:stateapmccheck();" color="primary">APMC</mat-radio- 
   button>
              <!--<mat-error 
    *ngIf="firstFormGroup?.controls?.choosereglevel?.hasError('required')">
                  Please choose one <strong>level.</strong>
              </mat-error>-->
            </mat-radio-group>
          </div>
          <br>
          <!--hidden select box-->
          <div id="ifstate" style="display:none;">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Registered With State: </mat-label>  
              <mat-select formControlName="choosestate" #selectstate>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let selectstate of registrationstate" 
    [value]="selectstate.value">
                  {{selectstate.viewValue}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div> 
            <!--second T&C select box-->
            <div id="ifapmc" style="display:none;">
              <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Registered With State: </mat-label>  
                <mat-select formControlName="choosestate" #selectstate>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let selectstate of registrationstate" 
    [value]="selectstate.value">
                    {{selectstate.viewValue}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field> 
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Registered With APMC: </mat-label>  
                <mat-select formControlName="chooseapmc" #selectapmc>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let selectstate of 
registrationapmcstate" 
    [value]="selectstate.value">
                    {{selectstate.viewValue}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you've got a syntax error inside your `if(...)` statements

When you use a single `=` sign it sets the property on the left of it to match the value on the right

To do a comparison you need a double `==`

So try `document.getElementById('state').checked == true` and `if document.getElementById('apmc').checked == true`